# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ScenariosViewCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 controllers on the one page: ScenariosViewCtrl and StoriesViewCtrl. StoriesViewCtrl is working fine, but for ScenariosViewCtrl I have an error: Argument 'ScenariosViewCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.

Both of them are declared in the same way in separate files:

scenariosview.controller.js

```
(function (){
    'use strict';
    function ScenariosViewCtrl() {
...
    };

    var app = angular.module('testLab');

    app.controller('ScenariosViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.players = "testing";
    });

});
```

storiesview.contoller.js

```
(function (){
    'use strict';
    function StoriesViewCtrl() {
    ...
    };
    var app = angular.module('testLab');

    app.controller('StoriesViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.players = "testing";
    }); 
});
```

And I have 2 separate directives 
scenariosview.directive.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    function scenariosviewDirective () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'ScenariosViewCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'scenariosViewCtrl',
            templateUrl: './Content/app/components/projectExplorer/scenariosExplorer/scenariosView/scenariosview.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            },
        };
    };
    angular.module('testLab').directive('rlScenariosView', scenariosviewDirective);
})();
```

storiesview.directive.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    function storiesviewDirective () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'StoriesViewCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'storiesViewCtrl',
            templateUrl: './Content/app/components/projectExplorer/scenariosExplorer/scenariosView/scenariosview.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            },
        };
    };
    angular.module('testLab').directive('rlStoriesView', scenariosviewDirective);
})();
```

My scenarioview.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon fa-folder-o" data-toggle="tooltip" title="New Folder"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon icon-book-open" data-toggle="tooltip" title="New Story"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon icon-note" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Story"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon fa-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="well wd-wide">
                    <abn-tree tree-data="storiesViewCtrl.data" tree-control="storiesViewCtrl.control" expand-level="2"></abn-tree>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-9">
        <div class="panel panel-info panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon icon-plus" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Scenario"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon fa-beer" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Background"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon fa-save" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Save Changes"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is in `storiesview.directive.js`. You define `function storiesviewDirective` but reference `.directive('rlScenariosView', scenariosviewDirective)`.

Comment: What's the goal of the `function ScenariosViewCtrl`? You create a controller `ScenariosViewCtrl` and then pass an anonymous function as a second argument. Instead you should pass a reference to the function `ScenariosViewCtrl`. The same case for `StoriesViewCtrl`. This doesn' really make sense. That shouldn't be the trigger for the error message, but you have to rethink the design of your app.

Comment: Also the property `controllerAs` is used as an alias to the real controller name. Having an alias `scenariosViewCtrl` for the `ScenariosViewCtrl` doesn't really help a lot. You still have to type the whole name. Better would be `controllerAs: 'scenarios'`.

Comment: @cezar The alias has the same name, because I thought it was a cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you define a module you have to define its dependencies -
   `angular.module('testLab', []);` (maybe you define it in another file?)
2. This makes no sense:

   ```
   function ScenariosViewCtrl() {
      ...
   };

   var app = angular.module('testLab');

   app.controller('ScenariosViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
       $scope.players = "testing";
   })
   ```

   Perhaps you meant:

   ```
   function ScenariosViewCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.players = "testing";
   };

   var app = angular.module('testLab');

   app.controller('ScenariosViewCtrl', ScenariosViewCtrl);
   ```
3. You can't create 2 directives with the same name `rlScenariosView`.

Comment: Spot on! Those are important issues, that should be solved. It isn't just the error message.

Comment: 1. I've tried `angular.module('testLab', []);`, but it doesn't help.

3. Sorry, it was a typo, I've just updated the code above.

Comment: 2. I've just tried your example:
function ScenariosViewCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.players = "testing";
};

    var app = angular.module('testLab');

    app.controller('ScenariosViewCtrl', ScenariosViewCtrl);

Got the same error

Comment: @Stivin You need to define `angular.module('testLab', []);` **first** and **once** (make sure the files are loaded in the right order). after that you can use `angular.module('testLab')`.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I have a separate file app.module, where I define testLab:

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('testLab', [
            'angle', 'ngResource'
        ]);
})();

Comment: @Stivin can you provide your `index.html` scripts loading code?

Comment: @Daniel I added my html to the post, I even don't call scenariosviewcontroller in it, but still got that error,

Comment: @Stivin that's not the relevant code. i need the code where you load the `js` files, where you have the `<script src="scenariosview.controller.js"></script>` line for example. If you don't have such a file - that's the cause of the error.

Comment: @Daniel Oh, I added a markup. AngularJS combines all my scripts by itself. In my html-code, made by AngularJS, I have all needfull references.

<script src="/Content/app/components/projectExplorer/storiesExplorer/storiesexplorer.controller.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/components/projectExplorer/storiesExplorer/storiesexplorer.directive.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/components/projectExplorer/storiesExplorer/storiesView/storiesview.controller.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/app/components/projectExplorer/storiesExplorer/storiesView/storiesview.directive.js"></script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101695/discussion-between-daniel-and-stivin).

Comment: @Daniel thanks for your help, at some strange moment it started to work. I don't know why, but now everything is right.